# AWS Elasticsearch service: Disable index auto creation (auto_create_index)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html mentions that auto creation of index can be disabled by

> Automatic index creation can be disabled by setting action.auto_create_index to false in the config file of all nodes.

How can this be done in Elasticsearch as a service using the Java AWSElasticsearchClient class or in any other way?

Comment: AWS Elasticsearch is quite a different beast where you don't get access to the node configuration. The only way to set that setting is via the `elasticsearch.yml` file on each node, but there's no way to access it as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

It is presently not possible to do this through the console.  There is no option in the Configure Domain screen (even under Advanced options)

What you can do is

```
   curl -X PUT "'https://<blah>.ca-central-1.es.amazonaws.com/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "persistent": {
        "action.auto_create_index": "false" 
    }
}
'
```

to set the cluster settings as documented in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-index_.html#index-creation